# Invertible product of noninvertible morphisms

Tags: category-theory, applications

This question may be too broad. Under what conditions is a product of noninvertible morphisms invertible?

Suppose that we model a finite number of different acts of observation (i.e., a thermometer reading, a spectrogram, a personality test,  etc.) by morphisms $f_i : S\rightarrow Q_i$ (for $1 < i < I$), where $S$ represents "the real world", the source of all possible observations, and $Q_i$ is our $i$-th space of possible observations.

Assume that the morphisms $f_i$ are each noninvertible (having neither a left nor a right inverse). Assume also that there exists an isomorphism $h : S \rightarrow \prod_i Q_i$ which is identical with the product of morphisms (the **universal arrow** of the product).

What, if anything, could be said about $f_i$ and $Q_i$?

Comment: The $f_i$ will almost never be isomorphisms. If these are sets and all the $Q_i$ are nonempty, then they will be surjective, because they're given by composing $h$ with the product projections $\prod_i Q_i \to Q_i$, which are surjective under these hypotheses.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The $f_i$ are, by assumption, not invertible, therefore not isomorphisms, right?

Comment: I suppose, but that's not a particularly interesting hypothesis; the interesting hypothesis is that $h$ is an isomorphism, and that's what I was working off of. My point is that this hypothesis already rules out the possibility that the $f_i$ are isomorphisms most of the time; the product projection $\prod_i Q_i \to Q_i$ is an isomorphism if all the $Q_j, j \neq i$ are the terminal object (so the one-element set) but almost never otherwise.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Interesting, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @KarlSchultheisz The isomorphism $h$ makes $S$ and $\prod_i Q_i =: P$ basically interchangeable. For instance, the composition of the canonical injections $i_i: Q_i \to P$ and projections $p_i: P \to Q_i$ with $h$ and $h^{-1}$ respectively (i.e. $h^{-1} \circ i_i: Q_i \to S$ and $p_i \circ h: S \to Q_i$) is also monic and resp. epic. And, yes, a $Q_i$ may be isomorphic to $S$ only if all the other $Q_i$'s are terminal objects (one-element sets, concretely speaking).

Comment: Geometrically speaking, $h$ defines sort of "curvilinear coordinates" on $S$; where $h^{-1} \circ i_i$ defines a "coordinate curve", while $p_i \circ h$ gives the "coordinate" of a point in $S$. Except that here is nothing known about the structure on $Q_i$ (which might be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) or $S$ (which might be a manifold).